# How to identify device type on WCF call

Tags: c#, android, ios, wcf

how can i detect if wcf call is requested by iOS or Android?

I have the following WCF method.

```
public Stream GetSmartLinkImage(string SmartLinkId)
{
        wmas_subsDataContext dc = new wmas_subsDataContext();
        string path = string.Empty;

        var fileRecord = from p in dc.Images where p.ImageTitle == "IMG0001" select p;

        if (fileRecord.Count() > 0)
        {
            path = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagesPath"].ToString() + "\\" + fileRecord.First().ImageName;
        }

        FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(path);

        return fs;
}
```

Comment: You can add something like "DeviceType" property inside SmartLinkId type and set that property on client side.

Comment: I need a way which should work automatically without sending a parameter . I need to know if there is way to detect it if calling phone is ios or android in my wcf method.

Comment: I am afraid that is not possible. According to these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286804/identifying-clients-in-a-wcf-service  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277256/identifying-wcf-client-id , you have to either pass the information as a parameter or include it in custom header. Without it, you wont be able to identify the client device.

Comment: Maybe if i get IIS header in my WCF method ?then i might be able to know the device type. can i?